# Chaining transformations in scikit pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm using the scikit pipeline to create a preprocess on a dataset. I have a dataset with four variables: `['monetary', 'frequency1', 'frequency2', 'recency']` and I want to preprocess all but `recency`. To preprocess, I first want to get the log and then standardize. However, when I get the transformed data from the pipeline, I get 7 columns (3 log, 3 standardize, recency). Is there a way to chain the transformations and so I can get the log and after the log perform standardize and only get a 4 feature dataset?

```
def create_pipeline(df):
    all_but_recency = ['monetary', 'frequency1','frequency2']

    # Preprocess
    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ( 'log', FunctionTransformer(np.log), all_but_recency ),
            ( 'standardize', preprocessing.StandardScaler(), all_but_recency ) ],
        remainder='passthrough')

    # Pipeline
    estimators = [( 'preprocess', preprocessor )]
    pipe = Pipeline(steps=estimators)

    print(pipe.set_params().fit_transform(df).shape)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to apply the `FunctionTransformer` sequentially. Try this!

```
def create_pipeline(df):
    all_but_recency = ['monetary', 'frequency1','frequency2']

    # Preprocess
    # Preprocess
    preprocessor1 = ColumnTransformer([('log', FunctionTransformer(np.log), all_but_recency)],'passthrough')
    preprocessor2 = ColumnTransformer([('standardize', preprocessing.StandardScaler(), all_but_recency)],'passthrough' )


    # Pipeline
    estimators = [('preprocess1', preprocessor1),('standardize', preprocessor2)]
    pipe = Pipeline(steps=estimators)

    print(pipe.set_params().fit_transform(df).shape)
```

**working example**

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import preprocessing

iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
df= pd.DataFrame(X,columns = iris.feature_names)

all_but_one = [0,1,2]

# Preprocess
preprocessor1 = ColumnTransformer([('log', FunctionTransformer(np.log), all_but_one)],'passthrough')
preprocessor2 = ColumnTransformer([('standardize', preprocessing.StandardScaler(), all_but_one)],'passthrough' )

# Pipeline
estimators = [('preprocess1', preprocessor1),('scalling', preprocessor2)]
pipe = Pipeline(steps=estimators,)

pipe.fit_transform(df)
```